# The component does not render its view in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a module in my Angular2 application named grid.module.ts which is located under folder grid.
  In this folder I have some components and all are imported and then exported to this module. Then this module is imported in app.module.ts

In grid folder I also have another module named grid-router.module.ts and also this module is imported in gird.module.ts.

grid-router.module.ts is as below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import{RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { GridComponent } from '../grid/grid.component';
import {InfoDetailsComponent} from './info-details.component'


@NgModule({

imports : [
component:GridComponent and it will dispalay the html view of GridComponent
 RouterModule.forChild([
   {path: 'grid', component:GridComponent},
   {path:'info/:id',component:InfoDetailsComponent}

   ])

   ],

 exports: [RouterModule]

 })

export class GridRouterModule {
}
```

GridComponent html view is named grid.component.html and is as below

```
grid.component.html

// a lot of html here
<div>
<info-ForWidget></info-ForWidget> //this is a selector of Component info-list.component.ts which is in the same level with grid.component.ts
</div>
```

info.list.component.ts render as its view info-list.html which is as below

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
<div class='panel-body'>
    <div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class='table'
               *ngIf='infos && infos.length'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let info of infos'>
                    <td><a [routerLink]="['/info',info.id]">
                        {{info.Name}}
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td>{{ info.Surname | uppercase}}
                  //some more html here
```

Till here everything works. 
  Now when I go to {{info.Name}} and click there in order to display the view of the component info-details.component the view is not rendered.

Note: The code is ok because in my service info-service.ts in do method of Observable I console.log getInfo(id:number) and the data are loaded and displayed in the console of Web Browser but the view is not rendered. 
 I am struggling with this for two days and I was not able to find any solution thats why I need some help from you guys

Comment: Can you attach a click event to your `<a>` elements  and `console.log(this.infos)` inside your component and share the results please? Example: `<a (click)="testClick($event)">{{info.Name}}</a>`

Comment: @echonax . I am out now and I do not have my pc with myself. Can you please say me if there is a mistake programmatically or is something I have missed to import?

Comment: I don't see a programmatic error, just need to debug the code.

Comment: @echonax I tried that and what I got is [Object,Object]

Comment: Can you iterate through this object? Like the `ngFor`. Can you see the `info`s? Do they have an `id` property?

Comment: @echonax As I previously said in my questin I can see the infos , even the infos for a particular id. In my service I have build a method for getting infos for a particular id and inside this method I have used except .get, .map I have used also .do in order to console.log the json file and I got the desired info for the particular id, but I do not know why it is not rendered in the view

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out. So can you iterate through the `infos` in your ts file when clicked? Does each file have an id?

Comment: @echonax I just did it and for now I have only two objects and both of them are displayed with their properties and values including id

Comment: Can you take a print screen of the object in your console.log?

Comment: @echonax I will do it a bit later since now I am out again. If you want I can give you my gmail address and I can send to you all the code . I will really appreciate if you help me

Comment: Ehm I don't think that'd be appropriate. I'll just wait for you to update

Comment: @echonax the response is like : {id:1, firstName:"BlahBlah", secondName:"BlahBlah", country:"Austria", otherInfos:[]} , {id:2, firstName:"Blah", secondName:"blah", country:"Austria", otherInfos:[]}